# Is there a difference between "Frenchmen" and "French men"?

Tags: demonyms

I was just reading a news article about a couple of *French men* and was wondering what (if any) the difference between that and *Frenchmen* is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"**Frenchmen**" could refer to [French people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenchmen) collectively, including French women. For example:

> *National Stereotypes in Perspective:
>   Americans in France, Frenchmen in
>   America* [[1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9042013656)]
>
> It seems that many lower-class Englishmen still harbour a Napoleonic dislike of Frenchmen  [[2](http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?t=329821)]

It can, of course, also refer to any smaller group of French persons:

> Where would you take a couple of
>   Frenchmen [in L.A. area]? [[3](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/497043)]

"**French men**" refers just to men from France (all of them or a specific group, depending on context), but not women. Example:

> French men are three times more likely than French women to kill themselves [[4](http://www.spiegel.de/international/world/0,1518,649715,00.html)]

I think that is the principal difference.

So, in the context of a news article about a couple of people, using "French men" at least makes it clear right away that all of them were men. Using "Frenchmen" would have left that unspecified.

Comment: I would also offer some synonyms of Frenchmen — "The French", "Frenchies", "Frogs" (the last one is offensive).

Answer (score 5):

*Frenchman* means *a person, especially a man, who is French by birth or descent* (*New Oxford American Dictionary*); a *French man* is a man who is from France.

Answer (score 2):

A Frenchman could mean a French ship. That seems an odd usage since ships are usually referred to as 'she', but there you are.

Comment: Wiktionary says it also means "A home-made tool used by bricklayers to cut excess mortar from newly pointed brickwork" but doesn't mention the ship definition.

Comment: And a red-legged partridge, too. You learn something new every day. Thanks for the suggestion, Shinto; I've bookmarked Wiktionary now.

Answer (score -2):

Basically a French man is a Frenchman and vice-versa, so the meaning is the same. Stylistically the word *Frenchman* seems a little old-fashioned. It's something I would avoid using, perhaps because it is associated with unacceptable terms like *Chinaman* for *Chinese man*.

Comment: I think this is more of a square/rectangle situation: All French men are Frenchmen, but not all Frenchmen are French men. I do, however, agree with your point about the subtle insult that could be implied by using the term *Frenchmen*.

Comment: _Chinaman_ seems to me different from _Frenchmen_. The exact comparison would be between _Chinaman_ and _Franceman_.