# Politically correct way to refer to a French individual

Tags: political-correctness, demonyms

What is currently accepted as the proper title for a person from France? Is it still the gender-specific Frenchman/Frenchwoman, or is Frenchperson the new term?
(I use French as just an example, obviously. Same question for English folks)

Comment: I've personally stuck to using "French person" or "British person" etc. but I have no idea if there's any consensus on that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between "Frenchmen" and "French men"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-a-difference-between-frenchmen-and-french-men)

Comment: Ngram shows an increasing  usage of 'French person',  but 'Frenchman' is  still more popular.

Comment: If _French_ is only an example, are you looking for a generic suffix for people from _any_ country. _man/men_ does work with French and English but doesn't work with a lot of nationalities; German, Japan, American etc. It does work with China but I'm not sure if _Chinaman/Chinamen_ is PC anymore.

Comment: If people are going to start promoting gender-specific designations for ethnicity or nationality, some obvious possibilities are *Normen/Norwomen* and *Germen/Gerwomen*. ;-)

Comment: @ErikKowal Nothing wrong with Norman (famous for their conquests), Norwoman seems less convincing.

Comment: "Rene" if you want to mimic cryptic cruciverbalists.

Comment: Also related: *[What do you call a Swiss man?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134776)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you call a Swiss man?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134776/what-do-you-call-a-swiss-man)

Comment: And this is exactly why using nicknames should be considered pragmatical, not pejorative. Frog, kiwi, limey are all gender-neutral, right?

Comment: It's *frog* isn't it? Haha only kidding but I was surprised to find frog described as "Slang: Extremely Disparaging and Offensive". Could any Frenchies comment? I thought it was about as offensive as calling the English "les rosbifs" or "limeys".

Comment: @Frank The Normans were originally Viking raiders until the King of France granted Rollo lands around Rouen (Normandy) which his descendants (including William the Conq) continued to hold. So Normans are not synonymous with French at all.

Comment: @TheMathemagician As a Frenchperson https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Frenchperson%2CFrench+person%2C+Englishperson%2C+English+person&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFrenchperson%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFrench%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEnglishperson%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEnglish%20person%3B%2Cc0, I don't find the terms "Frog," "Frogeater," "Froggie," and "Frank" particularly offensive or disparaging. :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_France

Comment: @TheMathemagician _French_, as the OP states, is just an example. Norman/Norseman

Comment: Let’s not forget Romen and Rowomen. This is sheer madness.

Comment: @ErikKowal - *German/Gerwoman* still has man in it twice. Consider *German/Gerbabe* instead.

Answer (score 4):

[*Frenchman*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frenchman) is not gender specific:

> 1) a native or inhabitant of France
>
> 2) a person who is of French descent

However, *Frenchman* **does not =** "*French man*" or "*French woman.*"

"*A French person*" constitutes the gender neutral form of these.

Use the accepted "Frenchman." To address someone as a "French person" sounds awkward and contrived in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It goes against the URL, but have you considered writing *Les Français*?

Comment: He is _un Français_. She is _une Française_.